# How to create quickblox App using api?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, quickblox, q-municate

I want to create multiple app on Quickblox for my application using api(ruby on rails), is there any way to create multiple Quickblox app using apis or javascript SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create QuickBlox applications programmatically, 
you can do it via Admin panel only.

If you need to automate it - potentially you can use some sort of [Selenium browser automation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: it is for automating web applications for testing purposes. how can i do for quickblox?

Comment: You can use it not only for testing purpose, but also to automate some job